# Entity FrameWork Core doesn't response where() query when adding under db.database.BeginTransaction() scope -Exception (Request timeout)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, transactions, mocking

I create generic add method that makes search in database given id and then i make changes on table and so i save it to database but when i add it under transaction scope it didn't worked. Thrown Request timeout Exception.It works on .net framework but doesn't work on .net core.I tried Mock<> but it does give me an error that platform doesn't support that.

```
   using (Y db = new Y())
        {
            using (var transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                db.Table.Add(new Table());
                db.SaveChanges();
                public static void add<Y>(Func<T, bool> condition)
                {
                    tableobject = Db.Set<Y>().where(condition).FirstOrDefault();
                    Db.Set<Y>().Add(tableobject);
                    Db.SaveChanges();
                }
                Transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I make some changes on question for representation real situation.
I find the solution.
This is a method that takes parameters and create new instance MyDbContext.
I called this method under transaction and if you work with .net core you cant create two dbcontext instance.You can work only one dbcontext. And I passed my Dbcontext class to method and the problem solved.